# Trying to make a Linked List that contains strings C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, linked-list

I am currently working on a linked list that will have strings that contain strings of information. I am using a struct that looks like this:

```
struct symbolTable
{
    string lexeme;
    string kind;
    string type;
    int offSet;
    symbolTable *nextSymbol;
    symbolTable *nextTable;
};
```

The insert function looks a bit like this:

```
void MPParser::insertToSymbolTable(string identifier, string type, string kind)
{
    tempOffset++;
    symbolTable *tempNode;
    tempNode = (symbolTable*)malloc(sizeof(symbolTable));
    tempNode->kind = kind; //Run Time error Here..
    tempNode->type = type;
    tempNode->lexeme = identifier;
    tempNode->offSet = tempOffset;
    tempNode->nextTable = NULL;
    tempNode->nextSymbol = root;
    root = tempNode;
}
```

The program compiles and then when I try to run and insert into the linked list I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5A6810D0 (msvcr110d.dll) in mpcompiler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access   violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

What is the correct way to assign a string to another one in a pointer? Or am I doing something completely wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: Consider `operator new` rather than `malloc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new` instead of `malloc()` so the string objects are constructed properly:

```
tempNode = new symbolTable;
```

And then use `delete` when you need to free the node later:

```
delete node;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace your code with

```
void MPParser::insertToSymbolTable(string identifier, string type, string kind)
{
    tempOffset++;
    symbolTable *tempNode;
    tempNode = new symbolTable;
    tempNode->kind = kind; //Run Time error Here..
    tempNode->type = type;
    tempNode->lexeme = identifier;
    tempNode->offSet = tempOffset;
    tempNode->nextTable = NULL;
    tempNode->nextSymbol = root;
    root = tempNode;
}
```

The `Access Violation` means that you are writing to non-assigned memory. And you must never use `malloc` in C++ as it does not call `constructors`, always use `new` to create dynamic objects and `delete` to free them.

Answer (score 1):

I did a very simple test under gcc 4.5.3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
  std::string a;
};

int main()
{
   A* ptr = new A;
   ptr->a = "hello";
   std::cout << ptr->a << std::endl;

   //A aStruct;
   A* ptr2 = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
   //ptr2 = &aStruct;
   ptr2->a = "hello again";   //simulate what you have done in your code
   std::cout << ptr2->a << std::endl;
   std::cin.get();
};
```

This will result in core dump since `ptr2` trying to access raw memory. However, if I uncomment:

```
//A aStruct;
//ptr2 = &aStruct;
```

It then works as expected. Therefore, you should use `new` instead of `malloc`. The reason is that `new` will call the constructor of the class to initialize the memory block allocated, however, `malloc` will not do that.